# How to set the Site-Root Relative Path (for localhost) on IIS on my web application

Tags: .net, iis, localhost, virtual-path

I create a new Web Site, in localhost, called Example1, on Visual Studio (2008); than if I wrote :

```
<img src="/private_images/club.png" />
```

the "path" that IIS should consider of should be `localhost/Example1/private_images/club.png`, but in fact it consider `localhost/private_images/club.png`.

So I should configure out IIS and my application in the right way (for each application). 
I know I can do it, because, in fact, online (from my hosting) it works as well.

How can I do it? Tried [this](http://forums.iis.net/t/1172105.aspx) solution, but on virtual path I already have `Example1`.

Also, reading [ASP.NET Web Project Paths](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms178116.aspx), seems that IIS doesnt recognize the "folder that is located under the Web site root" :

*site-root relative path, which is resolved against the site root. Site-root relative paths are useful if you keep resources that are used throughout the site, such as images or client script files, in a folder that is located under the Web site root.
The following example path assumes that an Images folder is located under the Web site root.*

So, in fact, what I'm looking for is how to change the **site-root relative path**

**EDIT** I know I should use `~` and put `runat="server"` on elements, but I want to avoid this workaround, configuring my website as my hosting has done online.