# How to specify path relative to site root?

Tags: asp.net

i want to specify a path to a file relative to the root of the web-site. e.g.

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="/Scripts/jquery-1.7.2.min.js"></script>
```

In ASP.net that causes problems because the *"root"* of the **site** can be different from the root of **server**.

e.g. Specifying `src` results in a `GET` from path

```
src="/Scripts/jquery-1.7.2.min.js"
http://localhost:64276/Scripts/jquery-1.7.2.min.js                           404

src="~/Scripts/jquery-1.7.2.min.js"
http://localhost:64276/WebSite/Adminstration/~/Scripts/jquery-1.7.2.min.js   404

src="~Scripts/jquery-1.7.2.min.js"
http://localhost:64276/WebSite/Adminstration/~Scripts/jquery-1.7.2.min.js    404

src="~/Scripts/jquery-1.7.2.min.js" runat="server"
500 Unexpected character '$'
```

How can i specify a **site relative** path when using HTML in ASP.net?

### See also

- [How to set the Site-Root Relative Path (for localhost) on IIS on my web application](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9700260/how-to-set-the-site-root-relative-path-for-localhost-on-iis-on-my-web-applicat)
- [ASP.NET relative path](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4571755/asp-net-relative-path)
- [Relative path from site root](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7960094/relative-path-from-site-root)
- [JQuery: Visual studio, error CS1056: Unexpected character '$'](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/200863/jquery-visual-studio-error-cs1056-unexpected-character)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

If you're using ASP.net MVC, then `src="~/scripts/blahblah"` should work fine.

If you're not using MVC, then you'll need to use something like:

```
<script src='<%= this.ResolveClientUrl("~/Scripts/jquery-1.7.2.min.js") %>' type="text/javascript"></script>
```

Comment: The `<%= this.ResolveClientUrl("~/Scripts/jquery-1.7.2.min.js") %>` worked perfectly. ***Perfectly!***